# Showing alert like menu alert in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I like to show alert like this:

[image]

And when I click the first settings icon, show an alert like this one:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Thats not an alert, thats a menu

Comment: ok , how to show a menu like this, when i click action bar menu icons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create android menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033274/how-can-i-create-android-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive that you have to group the subitems and embed in a one menu item.
Here is an example you can refer.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/id_group1"
    android:icon="@drawable/v3_actionbar_setting"
    android:orderInCategory="120"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_settings">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/subitem1"
            android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_settings"
            android:title="subitem 1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/subitem2
            android:icon="@drawable/image2"
            android:title="subitem 2">
        </item>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/group2"
    android:icon="@drawable/group2"
    android:orderInCategory="90"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="group 2">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/subitem21"
            android:icon="@drawable/subitem1"
            android:title="subitem1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/subitem22"
            android:icon="@drawable/sub2"
            android:title="sub2"/>
      </menu>
</item>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at this: [Android Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

You'll possibly find all you need.